# Mapping a class or a subclass of it in the same method

Tags: c#, .net, mapping

***Edit:*** *I just realized myself while typing in this question, that a simple solution can be achieved by using generics. I'm testing it, and will post it shortly...*

Given two entity classes (e.g. with data loaded from a database):

```
class PersonFromDb
{
    public string NameFromDb { get; }
    // ... other properties follow...
}

class ChildFromDb
{
    public PersonFromDb Person { get; }
    public int AgeFromDb { get; }
}
```

...And the following to "target" classes, to which I would like to map:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

class Child : Person
{
    public int Age {get; set; }
}
```

Now say I've written a mapping method for mapping `PersonFromDb` to `Person`:

```
public Person MapPerson(PersonFromDb person){ 
   return new Person { 
       Name = person.NameFromDb, 
       // ...
   }
}
```

And another method for mapping Child:

```
public Child MapChild(ChildFromDb child){ ... }
```

What I'd like to do here though, is map to call `MapPerson()` from within `MapChild()`, to avoid having to re-map all the common properties.

I can't use `MapPerson()` with `Child` however, since it returns a `Person`, not a `Child`.

Is there any pattern to help me resolve this, so I won`t have to repeat so much of the mapping logic here?

Comment: Have you heard about [Automapper](http://automapper.org/)?

Comment: Heard of it, but haven't really looked at it. I will though, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create generic person mapper, which will create and map any person type, which has parameterless constructor:

```
public <TPerson> MapPerson<TPerson>(PersonFromDb dbPerson){ 
   where TPerson: Person, new()
   return new TPerson { 
       Name = dbPerson.NameFromDb, 
       // ...
   }
}
```

Then use this generic person mapper to map child:

```
public Child MapChild(ChildFromDb dbChild)
{
    var child = MapPerson<Child>(dbChild.Person);
    child.Age = dbChild.AgeFromDb;
    return child;
}
```

Comment: Quick answer there! As I mentioned in my edit, I realized this myself when I was just about done writing the question. I decided to post it anyway, and I've already posted my own answer (which is basically the same as yours). I'll still give you the check though... Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my edit, I realized while writing this question that there is a simple solution using generics:

```
public T MapPerson<T>(PersonFromDb person) where T : Person, new() { 
   return new T { 
       Name = person.NameFromDb, 
       // ...
   }
}
```

This will allow for both of the following:

```
Person mappedPerson = MapPerson<Person>(instanceOfPersonFromDb);

Child mappedChild = MapPerson<Child>(instanceOfChildFromDb.Person);
```

I can then call the latter from `MapChild()`, allowing me to map the common properties in `MapPerson()`, then add the extra properties defined in `Child` afterwards, in `MapChild()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could rely on a mapping framework like AutoMapper to do the job.

Another solution could be to use interface instead of inheritance. Define a IPerson interface which would be implemented by Person et Child object. Then your MapPerson function could be somthing like MapPerson(IPerson target, PersonFromDb source) which would initialize the target object therefore being able to initialize Person or Child object.

Or you could use composition instead of inheritance and make the Person object an attribute of the child object.